# How can I resolve the 'Misordered multipart fields' error when using Nest.JS with GraphQL for a REST API to send files from ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, rest, graphql, nestjs

I have a bug where I am using Nest.Js and Graphql, everything works fine, but when I create an rest API for sending files from reactjs to nestjs, somehow Graphql is involved into this:

```
[Nest] 14240  - 06/05/2023, 1:21:37 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Misordered multipart fields; files should follow ‘map’ (https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec).
BadRequestError: Misordered multipart fields; files should follow ‘map’ (https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec).
    at Busboy.<anonymous> (D:\Codes\Projects\projectPractise\backend\node_modules\graphql-upload\processRequest.js:241:11)       
    at Busboy.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Busboy.emit (D:\Codes\Projects\projectPractise\backend\node_modules\graphql-upload\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:37:33) 
    at PartStream.<anonymous> (D:\Codes\Projects\projectPractise\backend\node_modules\graphql-upload\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:214:13)
    at PartStream.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (D:\Codes\Projects\projectPractise\backend\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:50:16)
    at HeaderParser.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at HeaderParser._finish (D:\Codes\Projects\projectPractise\backend\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:68:8)
    at SBMH.<anonymous> (D:\Codes\Projects\projectPractise\backend\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:40:12)
    at SBMH.emit (node:events:513:28)
```

And this is my endpoint in app.controller.ts for receiving files:

```
@Post('/uploadFile')
  @UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('files'))
  async uploadFile(@UploadedFiles() file: Express.Multer.File) {
    console.log('Hello --------------');
    console.log(file);
  }
```

Thank you so much!

I tried another pure nestjs project without graphql and it works fine, but somehow nestjs with graphql results in this error which I can not find the answer online.